# How to extract value from Jmeter get property and save as variables. These values will be used in api call

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

[getproperty values passed from Thread Group 1 to Thread group2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mji2b.jpg)

[Result from BeanShell assertion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDMFk.jpg)

- Step 1- USing jdbc request to get data from database with 2 columns and multiple rows.
- Step 2 - From ThreadGroup 1, Set property to the database results using ${__setProperty(StateCodeProperty,${stateDetails})};
- Step 3 - Access in Thread Group 2 by get property using beanshell assertion- String result = (vars.get("${__property(StateCodeProperty)}")); I need help on how to separate the columns and use it in api call. –

Comment: Welcome to SO!  
Can you please post your test plan, Please be aware that JMeter variables have thread scope, one cannot access variable created in one group in another thread group

Comment: Why do you want to get DB results in 1st ThreadGroup ? Can you not do the same in the 2nd ?

Comment: I want to run multiple threads. Separating database to different thread group will only access database once or it will call for each thread.

Answer (score 0):

In any case if you want to access the DB results in different Thread group then you can try to do something like this inside beanshell assertion (not sure though) -

```
ArrayList results = ${__property(StateCodeProperty)}; //it should return the object as an arraylist
for (int i; i < results.size(); i++) {     

    if (results.get(i).get("statecode").equals("NY")) { //iterating the results, 'statecode' is the name of your 1st column, similarly you can do for 'State'

        //Do your comparisons or whatever you like here             
    }      
}
```